# sed/awk regex with capture - how to get a somewhat simple regex to work?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, ksh

Sample contents of FILE.txt are shown below.  How would I modify the regex used by SED to do a capture which results in the desired output section?   Prefer to do this with POSIX awk or sed functions if possible.   I've looked into doing this solely with AWK, but am not following how you create the same behavior as a capture with the options it provides.

One of the problems I've run into trying various solutions is how to make the double-quotes optional.

```
sed -e 's/.Include .*"*\(.*\)"*/\1/g' FILE.txt


FILE.txt
##########################################################################
# Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI Multiviews
# Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# does not include the trailing slash. 
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml .html
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
Include /opt/file.conf
Include "/opt/file.conf"
Include /usr/bin/abcOutput.conf
Include /usr/bin/ed_Output.conf
###########################################################################


**Desired Output:**
/opt/file.conf
/opt/file.conf
/usr/bin/abcOutput.conf
/usr/bin/ed_Output.conf
```

Comment: Do you **really** want those `###########################################################################` lines to appear in the output? If not, fix your question.

Comment: Remove the `.` at the beginning of the regex, for starters.  You also need to make the match for the closing double quote work — use `[^"]*` instead of `.*` —

Comment: Thanks for the replies!   I'll check them out shortly.    One other quirk that may be relevant in the testing is that it needs to work on Redhat/OSx/AIX.   From prior testing the AIX boxes tend to give the most headache.  Not sure if they are picky in general, or the are stripped down, or using old versions of many utilities...   so, we'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extended regular expressions to avoid the unnecessary `\(` and `\)` and use `[[:blank:]]` as a character class that includes space and tab.  The `?` indicates 0 or 1 matches. The `+` indicates 1 or more.

`sed -rn 's/^Include[[:blank:]]+"?([^"]+)"?/\1/p'`

Note: The `-E` option for extended regular expression (instead of `-r`) makes it compatible with older versions of sed

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Assuming you don't want the '#############' strings in the output, and based solely on the example you've provided ...

How about a awk/sed combo:

```
$ awk '/^Include/ { print $2 } ' FILE.txt | sed 's/\"//g'
/opt/file.conf
/opt/file.conf
/usr/bin/abcOutput.conf
/usr/bin/ed_Output.conf
```

Perhaps not as efficient as a single sed command, but easier to understand/maintain (K.I.S.S.) and unless you're calling this kind of construct a *LOT* then the performance difference will be negligible.

Or a purely awk example (and a bit more efficient than the awk/sed idea):

```
$ awk '/^Include/ { gsub("\"","") ; print $2 } ' FILE.txt
/opt/file.conf
/opt/file.conf
/usr/bin/abcOutput.conf
/usr/bin/ed_Output.conf
```

Comment: or `awk -F '[ "]' '/^Include/ {print $2$3}' file`